# Computing no loss area within geometry to assess Global Forest Change?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

GEE [has a (great) tutorial on the Global Forest Change](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_forest_03a) data. 
In the tutorial, they show how to calculate the area of tree cover loss inside a geometry, by year.

Now, I would like to add the area of the geometry that had **no** loss.

I *think* I managed to achieve this, but

- I am not sure. What makes me not sure is the fact that when I sum the area of loss by year with the area of no loss, the result is 2.7% larger than the geometry's area.
- I wonder if there is a more efficient/elegant way of doing this, especially when it comes to output the information. In the code below, I do it for just one geometry, but in reality, I will do this for hundreds of geometries, and I would like to output the loss-by-year and the no loss data at once, preferably in tabular form.

Here's my code. You can also run it from GEE's code [editor by following this link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e4ceaf0099f8b30b10699870601748af).

```
// imports
var pt = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([-64.64, -9.27]),
    gfc = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2018_v1_6");

// create buffers
var bf1 = pt.buffer(10 * 1000);

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// this is straight from GEE's tutorial 
// -----------------------------------------------------------
var lossImage = gfc.select(['loss']);
var lossAreaImage = lossImage.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

var lossYear = gfc.select(['lossyear']);
var lossByYear = lossAreaImage.addBands(lossYear).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 1
    }),
  geometry: bf1,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

var statsFormatted = ee.List(lossByYear.get('groups'))
  .map(function(el) {
    var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
    return [ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), d.get('sum')];
  });
var statsDictionary = ee.Dictionary(statsFormatted.flatten());
print(statsDictionary);

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// now I would like to calculate the area of *no* loss
// -----------------------------------------------------------

// create mask
var mask = lossImage.gt(0);

// create new image
var nolossImage = mask.multiply(1).add(lossImage.multiply(mask.not()));

// do the same as before, but don't need to do it by year
var nolossAreaImage = nolossImage.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

var statsNoLoss = nolossAreaImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: bf1,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print(statsNoLoss);

// area of geometry (loss area + no loss area should equal this, right?)
print('Total area of geometry:', bf1.area())
```

The total loss area in this geometry (summing up the loss-by-year results) is 106,268,721 square meters. The no-loss area is 212,537,442 square meters. The sum is therefore 318,806,164 which is 2.7% greater than the geometry's 310,406,007 square meters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the masks you create.

```
var lossImage = gfc.select(['loss']);

function getArea(image){
  return image.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
            reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
            geometry: bf1,
            scale: 30,
            maxPixels: 1e9
          });
}

// calculate areas
print("Area Lost:", getArea(lossImage.gt(0)));
print("Area Not Lost:", getArea(lossImage.eq(0)));
print("Total Area", getArea(lossImage.gt(-1)))
```

This uses the fact that the band value for no loss is zero, and the band value for loss is greater than zero.

---

Original Answer:

It looks like it was due to the scale being set to 30 meters. Setting the scale to 1 meter yields figures that add up, though the total seems to be closer to 309k. [See this example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2e538a6ab9b5686dae4de1587b614b3c).